# restrict mdf file to be attached

Tags: sql-server-express

We can copy MDF and LDF files and paste them on other PC and easily attach it and view its contents!

I want to restrict that no one except me can easily attach my mdf files.

Encryption is not possible option for me. I am using SQL Server 2014 Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EFS, Encrypting File System, which is a windows feature. You will need to install a certificate for this under your account on the server. If anyone tries to copy or read the file and does not have permissions to the certificate, then they will get an error. Just be sure to grant the service account for the database engine access to the certificate or your database will not be usable until you do. I would recommend testing this before implementing.